# Rails Path Helper - same path for different namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm building a rails app.
It has two namespaces that use same tables.
Is there any way to use same path helpers for different models under different namespaces that access one common table?

```
# namespaces (= roles)
admin
user
```

```
# tables
users
posts
```

```
# models
User < ApplicationRecord
Post < ApplicationRecord
Admin::User < User
Admin::Post < Post
User::Post < Post
```

```
# in controllers
## Admin::Post#index
@admin_posts = Admin::Post.all

## User::Post#index
@user_posts = User::Post.all
```

```
# in views
## Admin::Post#index
<%= render "shared/posts/index", posts: @admin_posts %>

## User::Post#index
<%= render "shared/posts/index", posts: @user_posts %>
```

I would like to use shared template.
`<%= link_to post.title, post %>` works. It'll generate `admin/post/:id` or `user/post/:id` depends on the namespace of the instance.
But is there any way to generate `edit_post_path` that adapts to its namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`edit_post_path` seems can't do this, but you could try this:

```rb
<%= link_to post.title, [:edit, post] %>
```